# Sorting results from joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

While running this query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    pub.name AS publisher_name,
    pc.name AS placement_name,
    b.name AS banner_name,
    a.lead_id,
    a.partner_id,
    a.type,
    l.status,
    s.correctness,
    a.landing_page,
    t.name AS tracker_name,
    a.date_view,
    a.date_action

FROM actions AS a
LEFT JOIN publishers AS pub ON a.publisher_id = pub.id
LEFT JOIN placements AS pc ON pc.publisher_id = pub.id
LEFT JOIN banners AS b ON b.campaign_id = a.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN leads l ON
    l.lead_id = a.lead_id
    AND l.created = (
        SELECT MAX(created) from leads l2 where l2.lead_id = l.lead_id
    )
LEFT JOIN statuses AS s ON l.status = s.status
LEFT JOIN trackers AS t ON t.id = a.tracker_id
LIMIT 10
```

I am able to sort by every column from `actions` table. However when I try to for example `ORDER BY b.name` (from `banners` table, joined on `actions.banner_id`) or `ORDER BY l.lead_id` (joined from `leads` on more complex condition as seen above) MySQL is running query for a loooong time (most tables have tens of thousands records). Is it possible, performance-wise, to sort by joined columns?

Comment: You can improve your performance by adding a where clause so that you are not trying to sort as many records.

Comment: @DanBracuk, i don't think that's possible in this case - I want to sort results here, not filter them.

Comment: I guess you have index in all the fields where you applied the join.  Also try the command `explain` to see how is the query running.

Comment: My guess (and it's just a guess) is that your correlated subquery is slowing things down. Do you know how to rewrite it as an uncorrelated subquery? Also, LIMIT without ORDER BY (or perhaps GROUP BY) is fairly meaningless.

Comment: i dont see why you would do a left join and then order by the joined column? if you order by a column you actually want to have a value in it.

Comment: @Koryu, Well, I am fetching banner name (check `SELECT`) - now I'm just trying to order by its name.

Comment: i see, but you do a left join, so you got rows in ya result which not contain a banner (when a.campaign_id = null). means if you inner join banner you can order faster by banner name, because these null rows gets discarded.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the query with a inner join on the table where the column you want to sort on is.

For example, if you sort on `actions.banner_id`

```
SELECT ...
FROM actions AS a
  JOIN banners AS b ON b.campaign_id = a.campaign_id
  LEFT JOIN  *rest of the query*
```

You will get the same results unless there is not enough banners that can be joined to action to produce a total of 10 rows.

I'm guessing it's not the case otherwise you wouldn't be sorting on banner_id.

Comment: I don't know if that would be helpful. Still - I tried it and got the same result - had do cancel "Query running".

Comment: Is there an index on said column ?

Answer (score 0):

You could first filter (order by, where, etc.) your records in a subquery and then join the result with the rest of the tables.